# Wordpress, список подключаемых файлов в дочерней теме

Tags: php, wordpress

Используется дочерняя тема, чтобы при обновлении не пропали правки основной темы.
В основной теме пришлось немного изменить файл `plugins.min.js`, в котором находятся все плагины сайта в сжатой версии.
Так вот нужно из дочерней темы подключить этот изменённый файл `plugins.min.js`, но если в дочерней теме создать такую же структуру папок, которая в основной теме, к примеру:

```
/wp-content/themes/main-theme/assets/js/plugins.min.js
```

то данный скрипт не подключается из дочерней темы.
Код подключения всех скриптов находится в файле `functions.php` :

**funcitons.php**

```
...
# Including theme components
require_once get_template_directory().'/inc/includes.php';  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dfd_themes_scripts', 100);
```

**includes.php**

```
...
require_once get_template_directory().'/inc/helpers.php';
# Include scripts ans styles
require_once get_template_directory().'/inc/assets.php';
...
```

**assets.php**

```
function dfd_themes_scripts() {
...
wp_register_script('dfd_js_plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/plugins.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('dfd_js_plugins');
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно подключить `plugins.min.js` из дочерней темы, при том, что в файле `includes.php` импортируются намного больше файлов `.php`, не только `inc/assets.php` и `inc/helpers.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дочерней теме

```
// Важно, чтобы приоритет был больше 100
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'replace_dfd_themes_scripts', 200);
function replace_dfd_themes_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script('dfd_js_plugins');
    wp_deregister_script('dfd_js_plugins' );
    // Здесь stylesheet, а не template
    wp_register_script('dfd_js_plugins', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/plugins.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('dfd_js_plugins');
}
```

Сначала загружается код `functions.php` дочерней темы, потом код `functions.php`основной темы, которые лишь добавляют свои функции в список вызовов по событиям. Намного позже срабатывает событие `wp_enqueue_scripts`, внутри которого идут вызовы функций согласно приоритетам:

- 100 -> dfd_themes_scripts() основной темы - ставит в очередь скрипты, в том числе `dfd_js_plugins`
- 200 -> replace_dfd_themes_scripts() дочерней темы - удаляет из очереди скрипт   `dfd_js_plugins` основной темы и добавляет в очередь `dfd_js_plugins` дочерней темы.

По окончании этого события список скриптов и их порядок сформирован, но ещё ничего не выведено на страницу.

Далее срабатывает событие `wp_print_head_scripts`, которое выводит только те скрипты, что запланированы к выдаче в header.

После выдачи тела страницы срабатывает `wp_print_footer_scripts`, которое выводит из того же сформированного списка только те скрипты, что запланированы в footer.

Comment: подскажите, а файл `functions.php` из дочерней темы вроде загружается перед файлом `functions.php` основной темы. Как тогда данный код в дочерней теме может менять код, который ещё не выполнился из файла `functions.php` основной темы?

Comment: Я поправил и дополнил ответ.